# Facebook C# SDK not returning all information

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-sdk-4.0

My permission scope is defined in this:

```
var loginUrl = fb.GetLoginUrl(new
        {
            client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"].ToString(),
            client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"].ToString(),
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            response_type = "code",
            scope = "public_profile, email, user_friends, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_education_history, user_work_history, user_location" // Add other permissions as needed
        });
```

Then i get my access token this way:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient();
        fb.AppId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"].ToString();
        fb.AppSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"].ToString();

        dynamic result = fb.Post("oauth/access_token", new
        {
            client_id = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppID"].ToString(),
            client_secret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["facebookAppSecret"].ToString(),
            redirect_uri = RedirectUri.AbsoluteUri,
            code = code
        });
```

Then i assign my access token to the Facebook client this way:

```
fb.AccessToken = accessToken;
```

I have a custom class to retrieve the data from Facebook SDK:

```
dynamic userDetails = fb.Get("me", new { fields = "name, email, gender, birthday, education, work" });
dynamic userEducation = fb.Get("me?fields=education");
//2. Store details to be used
var facebookUserDetails = new UserFacebookDetails();
facebookUserDetails.Name = userDetails.name;
facebookUserDetails.Email = userDetails.email;
facebookUserDetails.Gender = userDetails.gender;
facebookUserDetails.SetBirthDayVals(userDetails.birthday);
```

I get data for name, email and gender only. I don't get info on birthday, education or work. I check the same endpoint at Facebook API Explorer and i get information. What is happening? Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: can you send ur code to login into fb plz, if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think i have figured the solution to this problem. The source of the problem stems at Facebook. I had not submitted my app for review and typically, those 3 scopes were among the set that needed submission before used.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your FB app => APP Review => Approved Items.
email, public_profile, user_friends are all supported on initial.
All others required scope in login will not return!
You might retrieve correct permissions when you login same with app's owner and unexpected permissions when login as other accounts after make your app public.
If you want to more permission... you must to submit to FB.
This problem also fxxx me for 1 week :))

[App Review ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVdQ4.png)